# Xcode -- what is $(SRCROOT)?

Tags: xcode, path

I am looking at an Xcode project that uses some libraries.  The project was created on a different computer, so I need to update some paths.  The library search paths all start with `$(SRCROOT)`.  What does that mean?

Comment: [`SRCROOT`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW38)

Comment: good answer here too: [What the different between SRCROOT and PROJECT_DIR?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43751741)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

It's the path to the directory containing the Xcode project.

Comment: The weird thing is that when I view the paths in the build settings, they all start with /Users/stevew.  When I double click to get the detail view for that setting, they instead all start with $(SRCRoot).  But there is no /Users/stevew directory on my computer.  So did it somehow get locked in to the location on the other computer?

Comment: Probably somebody defined SRCROOT using an absolute path - it's usually a convenient root directory for all the source in your project, but it shouldn't be an absolute path unless you've only got one development machine.

Comment: Adding to your answer, it is the directory of the local XcodeProject, so if you have MailCore under your project, MailCore's SRCROOT is the directory where you open the MailCore Project. 

XCode has this Usability issue where you can't scroll right on the project settings screen, so if you have a long path, you won't be able to tell this, thus I am adding to this answer for those with long lib names.
Thanks mipadi for the main answer.

Comment: what about `PROJECT_DIR`? What's the difference from `SRCROOT`?

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments ; see [question 36323031](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36323031/218152) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is it allowed to answer questions asked in comments?

Comment: Only if the other commenters are not missing out on upvotes.

Answer (score 21):

That's basically your project root directory defined by Xcode.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW38

Comment: Xcode Help documentation is now version based. Updated link for [Xcode 8.3 Build Settings reference](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.3/#/itcaec37c2a6).

Answer (score 17):

**Xcode SRCROOT**

```
<select_project> -> <select_target> -> Build Settings -> All -> <find_SRCROOT> -> <double_click_by_right_side> -> <click_plus>
```

`$(SRCROOT)`(aka `$(SOURCE_ROOT)`) is a path to your location where a`.xcodeproj` is.

It is simple to check, just put it in a field and Xcode gives you a tip

[image]

Comment: Where should I type $(SOURCE_ROOT) in to see it?

Comment: @Eldar I have added path where you can find it