# What the different between SRCROOT and PROJECT_DIR?

Tags: ios, xcode, environment-variables

In Xcode, we have to configure many paths in the **Build Settings**, then we will deal with the **$(SRCROOT)** and **$(PROJECT_DIR)** , But what the difference between them, can you show me an example, thx a lot.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Exchangeable in practice, while the documentation makes these subtle theoretical distinctions:

1. `SRCROOT`

   > Directory path. Identifies the directory containing the *target’s* source files: contains the path to the **project** file that defines the **target**.

   `SOURCE_ROOT` is an undocumented alias to `SRCROOT`
2. `PROJECT_DIR`
   Identifies the directory containing the **project** (`.xcodeproj`)
   `$(PROJECT_DIR)/build` is used as the create the default value for:

   - Intermediate Build Files Path `OBJROOT`
   - Build Products Path `SYMROOT`

   > Typically these paths are not set per target, but are set per-project or per-user.
3. `PROJECT_FILE_PATH`
   Identifies the project itself.
   Equivalent to `$(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME).xcodeproj`

Conceptually different (#1 is about the project which defines the **target** while #2 is about the project *independently* of any target), they are always pointing to the same location since you are, in essence, always building a target.

**References**

[Xcode 8.3 Build Settings reference](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.3/#/itcaec37c2a6)
[Xcode Build System Guide](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW49) (Retired 2016-09-29)

Answer (score 13):

`SRCROOT` & `PROJECT_DIR` are same macros have same effect.`PROJECT_DIR` makes more sense when talking about frameworks.

Comment: In my investigation, $(PROJECT_DIR) and $(SRCROOT) are some, both are root folder of project.