# Run script in Xcode build phase

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode8

In my package.json file I have a script that I'm running

```
node src/validateRun
```

i tried

```
/usr/local/bin/node "$SRC_DIR/src/validateRun.js"
```

but i got this error in xcode:

```
Command /bin/sg failed with exit code 1
```

I clicked on new run script phase inside Xcode but I'm not sure how to tell to run this this script.

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot of your Run Script Phase?

Comment: Not sure how to send images on stack overflow but basically what i did was this inside the Run script
```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
/usr/local/bin/node "$SRC_DIR/src/validateRun.js"
```

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '/validateRun.js' it's located in src of my app

Comment: try `SRCROOT` instead of `SRC_DIR`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719289/xcode-what-is-srcroot